# Alter design of selected linked item of bootstrap components

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap's linked item component. I want to change the css code slightly to alter the design of how the linked item looks like.

Here is how the linked items currently look like by default.
[image]

I want to change it to look something like this.
[image]

This would be a change in design for the 'active' class of linked item.
The code to generate a linked item is as below.

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

Comment: From what it looks like you would need an extra element after the link to make the arrow.

Comment: have you tried anything? Can you show us some css? Have a look at this for that triangle https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS, which you would probably want to apply to the `.list-group-item.active:after` selector ( a pseudo element should be sufficient, no need for extra markup)

Comment: @Pevara even if they used `::after` it wouldn't work. It would put it after the text in the link not the element itself.

Comment: have a look at my answer @Press, perfectly possible and quite easy even

Comment: @Pevara I didn't say it was impossible, just said you needed an extra element to get it done and that using `:after` on the link wouldn't achieve the desired result.

Comment: @Press no offense but there really is no need for an extra element here, the `:after` is more than sufficient: http://jsfiddle.net/njwmL64p/ Sorry, but I'm a strong believer of separation of markup and styling. If you have to add markup to achieve a certain styling you are most likely doing something wrong (though sometimes you have no choice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't be to hard. A triangle can be easily achieved with a border hack that is very well explained here: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS

If you apply that css to a `:after` pseudo element on the active list-group-item and finetune the positioning and size a bit, you should end up with some css that looks like this:

```
.list-group-item.active {
    position: relative;
}
.list-group-item.active:after {
    content: '';

    /* positioning */
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -1px;

    /* triangle */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 21px solid transparent;
    border-left: 24px solid #337ab7;
    border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
}
```

And a short demo: http://jsfiddle.net/njwmL64p/

Comment: Works well. The only thing I am wondering is .. if I could replace the 21px and 24px values with dynamic sizing to match the size of each linked item depending on the screen. Because it looked bigger when embedded on my code

Comment: I'm afraid not. The 21px is in fact just halve the height of the list-group-item, but since the actual pseudo element has a height of 0px you can't set the border width to 50%. I guess you could calculate and set it with javascript, but I don't think it can be done with just css. Perhaps an svg can provide a solution, but I'm no expert on svg's.